# Javascript - trying to understand how promises work when using loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, promise, event-loop

In this example, the order of `res` is preserved, because `await` is used within a for loop, which processes each promise sequentially. This means the loop waits for the current promise to resolve before moving to the next iteration.

```
async function processPromises(promises) {
    const res = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < promises.length; i++) {
        const val = await promises[i];
        res.push(val);
    }
    return res;
}
```

so you will have

```
res = [resolve1st, resolve2nd, resolve3rd, ...]
```

Now for below example

```
  const res = [];
  promises.forEach(async (_, i) => {
        const val = await promises[i];
        res.push(val);
  });
  return res;
```

The value of `res` is unpredictable. I know we can actually use `Promise.all` in this case, but I am eager to know how it works.

My guess is that, for each iteration in `forEach`, it runs asychronously. The promises are not required to resolve immediately before moving to the next iteration.
After all iteration of `promises`, `return res;` runs before all promises resolved(some of them are still in task queue waiting to be moved to the call stack).

If that's the case, I still can't explain to myself, how `The promises are not required to resolve immediately before moving to the next iteration`. Maybe I am wrong?

Comment: When you pass an `async` function to `.forEach()`, the initially returned Promise is completely ignored. The internal `await` calls from each iteration will complete whenever they complete, and not necessarily in order. Essentially, every `await` is started at almost the exact same time by the `.forEach()`, so the order in which the `.push()` calls are reached is not predictable.

Comment: from my understanding, `forEach` method doesn't care about the function that you pass in it.

Comment: If what you're trying to achieve is to process some asynchronous code in series, neither of those code snippets do that - so you may as well just `return Promise.all(promises)` - with or without the `async`/`await` - makes little difference